# lynx support for <input type="file"/>

Tags: lynx

I am using a website that accepts and reads local files. Local files can be dragged/dropped onto a special location on the web page. If you don't want to drag/drop, there's an "upload" button that opens a file picker dialog.

When I try this web page in lynx and choose the button, I get this message: `** Bad HTML!! No form action defined. **`

`<input type="file"/>` doesn't *need* a form to work. How can I access the "file picker" when using lynx? (This is assuming lynx even supports file picking, if only via a full-path prompt.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you cited doesn't come from a file input field – the "Upload" button that you have is **not** a `<input type=file>` at all; it's a *button* (either a `<button>` or an `<input type=button>`) that is supposed to display the actual file upload form via JavaScript (possibly "clicking" a hidden file field to cause the file selection dialog to open). It will not work in Lynx.

> `<input type="file"/>` doesn't need a form to work.

Practically speaking, it does, when you're using a browser that doesn't support JavaScript. Without there being JS code to handle the value locally, the only other operation possible with an `<input>` field of any type is to submit it as part of an HTML form.

However, it sounds like you're not even getting to that part anyway. An `<input type=file>` looks like this in Lynx:

[image]

That is to say, a "file" input field in Lynx looks like a text field, not like a button. It does function without a `<form>` around it, technically, in the sense that you can fill it in without receiving any error message (there's no browsing, you have to enter the filename), even if you can't actually upload it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I will have an opportunity to speak with the page developer next week. Maybe this site will simply never be lynx-friendly.

Comment: They could add a field in `<noscript>`, but you said there is no form currently, which implies that the page uses the JS "File access" API to process the data locally instead of uploading it to the server... In which case, even if the page had a plain HTML file entry, there still wouldn't be anything to process it locally without JS support.

Comment: You are correct; there is no form and they're relying on JS "File access." I spoke with the developer and, well, everything is done in the page with JS. That's that. Thanks for all the info!